# Jetbrains PHPStorm 5.0.4 tells me I have a Duplicated jQuery Selector

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the piece of jQuery I wrote,

```
$('#editUser').click(function() {
    if ($(".selectedTR")[0]) {
        if($('.form-actions').is(':visible')) {
            $('.form-actions').slideUp('slow',function() {
                $('.form-actions > h3').text("Edit");
            }).css('display', 'none');
        }

        $('.form-actions').css('display', 'block').slideDown('slow');
    } else {
        alert("Please select a user");
    }
});
```

How can I remove the duplicated selectors?

Comment: declare a variable for `$('.form-actions')` and use it.

Comment: PHPStorm WTF. I'm getting tired of constantly telling people to cache their queries.

Comment: @ŠimeVidas huh ? Its good phpstorm is highlighting inefficeint code, isn't it ?

Comment: @NimChimpsky LOL, I meant FTW, not WTF.

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com might be better suited for this sort of question, since there's nothing actually broken in your code.

Comment: PHPStorm is nice, but yea just started using jQuery heavily in my project so trying to get used to it's ways.

Comment: @Blazemonger I guess you're right, sorry for that!

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can cache the selector by putting it in a variable. Try this:

```
$('#editUser').click(function() {
    if ($(".selectedTR").length) { 
        var $formActions = $('.form-actions');
        if ($formActions.is(':visible')) {
            $formActions.slideUp('slow', function() {
                $formActions.children('h3').text("Edit");
            }).css('display', 'none');
        }
        $formActions.css('display', 'block').slideDown('slow');
    } else {
        alert("Please select a user");
    }
});
```

Comment: You could even replace `if ($formActions.is(':visible')) {
            $formActions.slideUp(` with `$formActions.filter(':visible').slideUp(`