# Jquery Duplicate Jquery selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, contact-form

I am trying to build a contact form error caller.

My Jquery code just said Duplicate jQuery Selector [closest thing i could find](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13705707/jetbrains-phpstorm-5-0-4-tells-me-i-have-a-duplicated-jquery-selector) to the same problem as me. but i tried implementing the fix people gave on that question but it did not work. ill show what i tried. and maybe someone sees the problem here.

here is my code.

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#submit").click(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();

                var $name = $("#name"),
                    $email = $("#email"),
                    $phone = $("#phone"),
                    $address = $("#address"),
                    $message = $("#message");

                var $name_error = $("#name_error"),
                    $email_error = $("#email_error"),
                    $telephone_error = $("#telephone_error"),
                    $message_error = $("#message_error"),
                    $address_error = $("#address");


                var data = {
                    name: $name.val(),
                    email: $email.val(),
                    telephone: $phone.val(),
                    address: $address.val(),
                    message: $message.val()
                };

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/api/contact/submit",
                    data: data,
                    success: function (data) {
                        console.log(data);
                        $('#error_list').empty();
                        $('#show_error').hide();
                        if (data.hasOwnProperty('errors')) {
                            // Show de errors.

                            $.each(data.errors, function (entry) {
                                switch (entry) {
                                    case 'email':
                                        $('#error_list').append('<li>' + data.errors.email + '</li>');
                                        $email_error.show();
                                        break;
                                    case 'name':
                                        $('#error_list').append('<li>' + data.errors.name + '</li>');
                                        $name_error.show();
                                        break;
                                    case 'message':
                                        $('#error_list').append('<li>' + data.errors.message + '</li>');
                                        $message_error.show();
                                        break;
                                    case 'message':
                                        $telephone_error.show();
                                        break;
                                    case 'message':
                                        $address_error.show();
                                        break;
                                }
                            });


                            $('#show_error').show();
                        }
                        console.log("banaan");
                        // Reset het form
                        // Show succcess
                        $("#contact-form").trigger('reset');
                        $("#success_message").show();
                    },
                    dataType: "json"
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

The `var` tags give me this error. and it said at as example `("#name")` that it is an duplicate selector. but at first i had the vars the same. so `var $name` and `var $name_error`were the same value: `("#name")` now i changed one to  `("#name_error")` and nowhere else i call uppon  `("#name")` and it keeps saying that its an duplicate.

if someone can explain this error to me or have an fix for this i would be happy the documentation says the same. that you have to give every value a specific name and i did just that but still its saying the error.

Comment: Address is duplicated.

Comment: yes the other guy just pointed that out. but still thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are selecting `#address` twice

```
$address = $("#address"),
(...)
$address_error = $("#address");
```

My guess is, you should have this code:

```
$address_error = $("#address_error")
```

By the same token, you have the following duplicate selectors in your code:

```
$('#error_list')
$('#show_error')
```

the following code does not have any Duplicate Jquery Selector messages in PhpStorm:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#submit").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var $name = $("#name"),
                $email = $("#email"),
                $phone = $("#phone"),
                $address = $("#address"),
                $message = $("#message");

            var $name_error = $("#name_error"),
                $email_error = $("#email_error"),
                $telephone_error = $("#telephone_error"),
                $message_error = $("#message_error"),
                $address_error = $("#address_error");

            var $error_list = $('#error_list'),
                $show_error = $('#show_error');


            var data = {
                name: $name.val(),
                email: $email.val(),
                telephone: $phone.val(),
                address: $address.val(),
                message: $message.val()
            };

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "/api/contact/submit",
                data: data,
                success: function (data) {
                    console.log(data);
                    $error_list.empty();
                    $show_error.hide();
                    if (data.hasOwnProperty('errors')) {
                        // Show de errors.

                        $.each(data.errors, function (entry) {
                            switch (entry) {
                                case 'email':
                                    $error_list.append('<li>' + data.errors.email + '</li>');
                                    $email_error.show();
                                    break;
                                case 'name':
                                    $error_list.append('<li>' + data.errors.name + '</li>');
                                    $name_error.show();
                                    break;
                                case 'message':
                                    $error_list.append('<li>' + data.errors.message + '</li>');
                                    $message_error.show();
                                    break;
                                case 'message':
                                    $telephone_error.show();
                                    break;
                                case 'message':
                                    $address_error.show();
                                    break;
                            }
                        });


                        $show_error.show();
                    }
                    console.log("banaan");
                    // Reset het form
                    // Show succcess
                    $("#contact-form").trigger('reset');
                    $("#success_message").show();
                },
                dataType: "json"
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: oh. ye thats a brainfart. but still i just changed it so im upvoting you but it didnt get rid of the error.

Comment: Every single $("#Variable") gives me the error or poppup message and is highlighted.

Comment: You also have `case 'message'` three times in your code. Please see the code I pasted. Should not give you any of those errors anymore (at least within this file)

Comment: YES your the best. your edit addition fixed it tottaly. thank you!